# how to retrieve and save image from one table of sql server to another table

Tags: sql

I have two table in my database, and want to retrieve an image from one table and save to another table. 
I tried it but each time face buffer parameter error.

Comment: Please provide some code. How are the images stored in SQL Server (Filestream, Link, Binary, ...)?

Comment: And a typical `INSERT INTO x(imagecolumn) SELECT imagecolumn FROM y WHERE ...` doesn't work?